# How to Autorelease a CGImageRef?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I have a method that returns a `CGImageRef` object. It contains this call:

```
CGImageRef posterFrame = [avAssetImage copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:nil error:&error];
...
return posterFrame;
```

This situation, as I understand it, calls for an autorelease. But I have no idea how to do it. I've tried using `CFCollectable()`, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using garbage collection, use `CFMakeCollectable(posterFrame)`. If you're using traditional memory management, it's very straightforward:

```
return (CGImageRef)[(id)posterFrame autorelease];
```

You cast the `CFTypeRef` (in this case, a `CGImageRef`) to an Objective-C object pointer, send it the `-autorelease` message, and then cast the result back to `CGImageRef`. This pattern works for (almost) any type that's compatible with `CFRetain()` and `CFRelease()`.

Comment: Not the prettiest construction, but works a treat. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

Core Graphics (and Core Foundation) doesn't have an [autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAutoreleasePool), so if you want to return your `CGImageRef` you need to either name your function containing `Create`(f.e. `MyCreatePosterImage()`) or return `UIImage` object instead:

```
CGImageRef posterFrame = [avAssetImage copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:nil error:&error];
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:posterFrame];
CGImageRelease(posterFrame);
return result;
```